# Python - Multi Listbox to Entry box

Tags: python, tkinter

I am using code for a multi listbox (http://code.activestate.com/recipes/52266-multilistbox-tkinter-widget/)

This is creating columns of data for the user to select from, I would like when the user Listboxselect that the columns from the record get populated into different Entry boxes.

I can get this to work in a standard Listbox using .bind .delete .insert within a function but because the data within the dictionary is different sizes it looks ugly:)

I would really like to stick with the code below but I cannot get the function to work. Really appreciate if someone could point me in the right direction, trying to figure this for a few days but going around in circles

> Code I would like to resolve

```
def on_selection(event):
        line = event.widget.get(event.widget.curselection())

        locationent.delete(0, 'end')
        cuspnent.delete(0, 'end')
        locationent.insert('end', line[0:1])
        cuspnent.insert('end', line[1:2])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    ttk.Label(leftbottomframe, text='**Select count record from MultiListbox by doubleclick**').pack()
    mlb = MultiListbox(leftbottomframe, (('Location', 15),('RRD PN', 15),("Lot/Serial", 15), ('Description', 35), ('Customer PN', 15)))
    for i in dic:
         mlb.insert(END, (dic[i]['Location'],dic[i]['Item Number'],dic[i]['Lot/Serial'],dic[i]['Description'],dic[i]['Cross_Reference']))


    mlb.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>', on_selection)
```

> Larger Set of Code using for Multi Listbox

```
data_file= pd.read_excel('CC 180763.xlsx',sheet_name='Sheet1',header=0,converters={'Location':str,'Item Number':str,'Cross_Reference':str,'Description':str})

print (data_file)

dic = data_file.set_index('Reference').transpose().to_dict(orient='dict')# data_file.to_dict(orient='records')


class MultiListbox(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, lists):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.lists = []
        for l, w in lists:
            frame = Frame(self);
            frame.pack(side=LEFT, expand=YES, fill=BOTH)
            Label(frame, text=l, borderwidth=1, relief=RAISED).pack(fill=X)
            lb = Listbox(frame, width=w, borderwidth=0, selectborderwidth=0,
                         relief=FLAT, exportselection=FALSE)
            lb.pack(expand=YES, fill=BOTH)
            self.lists.append(lb)
            lb.bind('<B1-Motion>', lambda e, s=self: s._select(e.y))
            lb.bind('<Button-1>', lambda e, s=self: s._select(e.y))
            lb.bind('<Leave>', lambda e: 'break')
            lb.bind('<B2-Motion>', lambda e, s=self: s._b2motion(e.x, e.y))
            lb.bind('<Button-2>', lambda e, s=self: s._button2(e.x, e.y))
        frame = Frame(self);
        frame.pack(side=LEFT, fill=Y)
        ttk.Label(frame, borderwidth=1, relief=RAISED).pack(fill=X)
        sb = Scrollbar(frame, orient=VERTICAL, command=self._scroll)
        sb.pack(expand=YES, fill=Y)
        self.lists[0]['yscrollcommand'] = sb.set

    def _select(self, y):
        row = self.lists[0].nearest(y)
        self.selection_clear(0, END)
        self.selection_set(row)
        return 'break'

    def _button2(self, x, y):
        for l in self.lists: l.scan_mark(x, y)
        return 'break'

    def _b2motion(self, x, y):
        for l in self.lists: l.scan_dragto(x, y)
        return 'break'

    def _scroll(self, *args):
        for l in self.lists:
            apply(l.yview, args)

    def curselection(self):
        return self.lists[0].curselection()

    def delete(self, first, last=None):
        for l in self.lists:
            l.delete(first, last)

    def get(self, first, last=None):
        result = []
        for l in self.lists:
            result.append(l.get(first, last))
        if last: return apply(map, [None] + result)
        return result

    def index(self, index):
        self.lists[0].index(index)

    def insert(self, index, *elements):
        for e in elements:
            i = 0
            for l in self.lists:
                l.insert(index, e[i])
                i = i + 1

    def size(self):
        return self.lists[0].size()

    def see(self, index):
        for l in self.lists:
            l.see(index)

    def selection_anchor(self, index):
        for l in self.lists:
            l.selection_anchor(index)

    def selection_clear(self, first, last=None):
        for l in self.lists:
            l.selection_clear(first, last)

    def selection_includes(self, index):
        return self.lists[0].selection_includes(index)

    def selection_set(self, first, last=None):
        for l in self.lists:
            l.selection_set(first, last)

def on_selection(event):
        line = event.widget.get(event.widget.curselection())

        locationent.delete(0, 'end')
        cuspnent.delete(0, 'end')
        locationent.insert('end', line[0:1])
        cuspnent.insert('end', line[1:2])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    ttk.Label(leftbottomframe, text='**Select count record from MultiListbox by doubleclick**').pack()
    mlb = MultiListbox(leftbottomframe, (('Location', 15),('RRD PN', 15),("Lot/Serial", 15), ('Description', 35), ('Customer PN', 15)))
    for i in dic:
         mlb.insert(END, (dic[i]['Location'],dic[i]['Item Number'],dic[i]['Lot/Serial'],dic[i]['Description'],dic[i]['Cross_Reference']))


    mlb.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>', on_selection)

    mlb.pack(expand=YES, fill=BOTH)
```

Answer (score 1):

> **Question**:  when the user Listboxselect that the columns from the record get populated

1. Remove this, as it bind to the `Frame`, this is not what you want.

   ```
   #mlb.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>', on_selection)
   ```
2. Add the following to `class MultiListbox`:

   ```
   class MultiListbox(Frame):
       def __init__(self, master, lists):
           Frame.__init__(self, master)
           self.labels = []
           ...
           for l, w in lists:
               self.labels.append(l)
               lb.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>', self.on_selection)
               ...
   ```
3. Remove the following, as bind any `B1...` will prevent `<<ListboxSelect>>` event.

   > **Note**: If you need these bindings otherwise, you have to chain to `self.on_selection`.

   ```
               #lb.bind('<B1-Motion>', lambda e, s=self: s._select(e.y))
               #lb.bind('<Button-1>', lambda e, s=self: s._select(e.y))
   ```
4. Make `def on_selection(...` a methode of `class MultiListbox`:

   ```
       def on_selection(self, event):
           # Get the current selected row
           row = event.widget.curselection()[0]

           # Clear previous selected row, select the current row
           self.selection_clear(0, END)
           self.selection_set(row)

           # Create a dict record from all self.lists
           # Use self.labels as dict key
           record = {}
           for column, lb in enumerate(self.lists):
               record[self.labels[column]] = lb.get(row, row)[0]

           print('Selection[{}]:{}'.format(row, record))
   ```

> **Usage**:

```
        mlb = MultiListbox(leftbottomframe,
                           (('Location', 15),('RRD PN', 15),("Lot/Serial", 15),
                            ('Description', 35), ('Customer PN', 15)))

        for n in range(3):
            mlb.insert(END, ['{}_{}'.format(label, n) for label in mlb.labels])

        mlb.pack(expand=YES, fill=BOTH)
```

> **Output**:
>
> ```
> Selection[0]:{'Description': 'Description_0', 'Location': 'Location_0', 'Customer PN': 'Customer PN_0', 'Lot/Serial': 'Lot/Serial_0', 'RRD PN': 'RRD PN_0'}
> Selection[1]:{'Description': 'Description_1', 'Location': 'Location_1', 'Customer PN': 'Customer PN_1', 'Lot/Serial': 'Lot/Serial_1', 'RRD PN': 'RRD PN_1'}
> Selection[2]:{'Description': 'Description_2', 'Location': 'Location_2', 'Customer PN': 'Customer PN_2', 'Lot/Serial': 'Lot/Serial_2', 'RRD PN': 'RRD PN_2'}
> ```

***Tested with Python: 3.5***