# tkinter Multilistbox custom event binding problem

Tags: python, tkinter, listbox

So my project is about showing information from a database in conjunction with images.
The idea is the following:

I have a database that describes images. One table has general information, like which color is contained in which image and another table has more granular information, like where that color can be found, etc.

When I launch a search, I want two windows to open (`ClassTwo` and `ClassThree`).
Instead of the first Window that only contains a Button to launch the search, my full application contains fields that are used to filter a database request. When I launch that search I want e.g. all images with the color green in them, so `ClassTwo` would list all images with that color, along with additional metadata.

`ClassThree` would then list all areas that contain the same color, but with a bit more detail, like position in the image and size, etc.
Upon clicking on either of the `MultiListbox`, I want to open an ImageViewer that shows the image.
In case of `ClassThree`, I would also directly highlight the area that I clicked on, so both classes would have functions bound to the `MultiListbox`.

My problem is with the binding of the `Listboxes`, that does not work properly. When I use e.g. `image_parts_info_lb.bind()` the function is not triggered at all. When i use `image_parts_info_lb.bind_all()` only the function of the last `MultiListbox` is triggered.

You can find the original `Python2` version of the `MultiListbox` in the comment of the class.

Here is my code

```
import tkinter as tk

class MultiListbox(tk.Frame):
#original Python2 code here:
#https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/python-cookbook/0596001673/ch09s05.html
    def __init__(self, master, lists):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.lists = []
        print(lists)
        for l,w in lists:
            frame = tk.Frame(self)
            frame.pack(side='left', expand='yes', fill='both')
            tk.Label(frame, text=l, borderwidth=1, relief='raised').pack(fill='x')
            lb = tk.Listbox(frame, width=w, borderwidth=0, selectborderwidth=0,
                         relief='flat', exportselection=False, height=16)
            lb.pack(expand='yes', fill='both')
            self.lists.append(lb)
            #commented out functions that were not necessary, as suggested in the comments
            #lb.bind('<B1-Motion>', self._select)
            lb.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>', self._select)
            #lb.bind('<Leave>', lambda e: 'break')
            lb.bind('<MouseWheel>', lambda e, s=self: s._scroll_mouse(e))
            #lb.bind('<Button-2>', lambda e, s=self: s._button2(e.x, e.y))
        frame = tk.Frame(self)
        frame.pack(side='left', fill='y')
        tk.Label(frame, borderwidth=1, relief='raised').pack(fill='x')
        sb = tk.Scrollbar(frame, orient='vertical', command=self._scroll)
        sb.pack(expand='yes', fill='y')
        self.lists[0]['yscrollcommand']=sb.set

    def _select(self, event):
        w = event.widget
        curselection = w.curselection()

        if curselection:
            self.selection_clear(0, self.size())
            self.selection_set(curselection[0])

    def _button2(self, x, y):
        for l in self.lists:
            l.scan_mark(x, y)
        return 'break'

    def _b2motion(self, x, y):
        for l in self.lists: l.scan_dragto(x, y)
        return 'break'

    def _scroll(self, *args):
        for l in self.lists:
            l.yview(*args)
        return 'break'

    def _scroll_mouse(self, event):
        for l in self.lists:
            l.yview_scroll(int(-1*(event.delta/120)), 'units')
        return 'break'

    def curselection(self):
        return self.lists[0].curselection()

    def delete(self, first, last=None):
        for l in self.lists:
            l.delete(first, last)

    def get(self, first, last=None):
        result = []
        for l in self.lists:
            result.append(l.get(first,last))
        if last: return apply(map, [None] + result)
        return result

    def index(self, index):
        self.lists[0].index(index)

    def insert(self, index, *elements):
        for e in elements:
            for i, l in enumerate(self.lists):
                l.insert(index, e[i])

    def size(self):
        return self.lists[0].size()

    def see(self, index):
        for l in self.lists:
            l.see(index)

    def selection_anchor(self, index):
        for l in self.lists:
            l.selection_anchor(index)

    def selection_clear(self, first, last=None):
        for l in self.lists:
            l.selection_clear(first, last)

    def selection_includes(self, index):
        return self.lists[0].selection_includes(index)

    def selection_set(self, first, last=None):
        for l in self.lists:
            l.selection_set(first, last)

class ClassOne:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.frame = tk.Frame(self.master)
        self.create_elements()
        self.frame.pack()

    def create_elements(self):
        search_button = tk.Button(self.frame, text = "Launch searches", command = \
        self.call_other_classes)
        search_button.grid(row = 2, column = 0, padx = 20, pady = 10)
        exit_button = tk.Button(self.frame, text = "Exit", command = self.master.quit)
        exit_button.grid(row = 2, column = 1, padx = 20, pady = 10)

    def call_other_classes(self):
        self.classes_list = []
        self.classes_list.append(ClassTwo(self.master))
        self.classes_list.append(ClassThree(self.master))

class ClassTwo:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.frame = tk.Frame(tk.Toplevel(self.master))
        self.frame.pack()
        self.create_elements()
        self.fill_image_listbox()       

    def create_elements(self):
        #placement of the custom MultiListbox
        self.available_images_lb = MultiListbox(self.frame, (('stuff1', 0), ('stuff1', 0), \
        ('stuff1', 0), ('stuff1', 0), ('stuff1', 0) ))
        self.available_images_lb.grid(row = 1, column = 1)
        self.available_images_lb.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>', self.print_stuff_two)
        #Button
        exit_button = tk.Button(self.frame, text = "Quit", command = self.frame.quit)
        exit_button.grid(row = 2, column = 1, padx = 20, pady = 10)


    def fill_image_listbox(self):
        image_info = [5*['ABCD'],5*['EFGH'],5*['JKLM'],5*['NOPQ'],5*['RSTU'], 5*['VWXY']]
        for item in image_info:
            self.available_images_lb.insert('end', item)

    def print_stuff_two(self, event):
        print('Class Two active')

class ClassThree:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.frame = tk.Frame(tk.Toplevel(self.master))
        self.create_elements()
        self.frame.pack()
        self.fill_imageparts_listbox()

    def create_elements(self):  
        self.image_parts_info_lb = MultiListbox(self.frame, (('stuff1', 0), ('stuff1', 0), \
        ('stuff1', 0), ('stuff1', 0), ('stuff1', 0) ))
        self.image_parts_info_lb.grid(row = 1, column = 1)
        self.image_parts_info_lb.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>', self.print_stuff_three)

    def fill_imageparts_listbox(self):
        self.image_parts_info_lb.delete(0, 'end')
        image_part_info = [5*['1234'],5*['5678'],5*['91011']]
        for item in image_part_info:
            self.image_parts_info_lb.insert('end', item)

    def print_stuff_three(self, event):
        print('Class Three active')     

def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title('Image Viewer')
    root.geometry('500x150+300+300')
    my_class_one = ClassOne(root)
    root.mainloop()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Instead of the printing functions I would launch a simple Image Viewer and use Pillow to highlight areas in the image. That functionality is implemented and works well, only the function binding to the custom `Listbox` is not working as it should.

I am open to any input. Also, if you have any recommendations for coding patterns, feel free to let me know.

Comment: Read [`class MultiListbox(Frame):`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59430759/7414759) and [`class MultiListbox(Frame):`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54737769/7414759)

Comment: Thanks so far, I already read the first thread (see my code) didn't find the second apparently. I removed the bindings, except for MouseWheel. What I don't understand, is how can I then trigger a function in one of the classes, to e.g. launch my Image Viewer? Mind answering in a bit more detail?

Comment: I see one thing wrong in `ClassTwo.create_elements()`. Change the call to `bind()` to `self.available_images_lb.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>', self.print_stuff_two)` which will avoid calling `self.print_stuff_two()` at that point (which causes a `TypeError: print_stuff_two() missing 1 required positional argument: 'event'`).

Comment: True, thanks for the hint, will also change it in the code of the post. This was just one of many attempts to get this to work properly. I also tried something along the lines of  `self.available_images_lb.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>', lambda e, s= self: self.print_stuff_two(e))`. Sadly this also did not solve the problem.

Comment: @stovfl what I want is, when I click on any of the list elements, to trigger the `print_stuff_x` function. E.g. in ClassTwo `print_stuff_two` should be triggered, as it is bound to the MultiListbox. If I remove the binding, as you suggested, it can't be triggered anymore, so how would I do that then? Just click the 'Launch searches' button and in one of the Listboxes click on any entry. WIth the regular `.bind` nothing happens. Change that code to `.bind_all()` and it will print something.

Comment: @n00by0815 ***" it is bound to the MultiListbox."***: You are misguided, `.available_images_lb.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>'` binds to a `Frame`. A `Frame` never get a `'<<ListboxSelect>>'` event. You have pass a `callback` to `MultiListbox` wich get called from inside `def _select(...`.

Comment: @martineau I did very well get your point (code was already changed). I was just trying everything that I could think of and forgot to change the code back.

Comment: @stovfl  could you please give me an example of how that is done? Or do I need to monitor the value of MLB.currentselection and trigger my function, when that value has changed?

Comment: @n00by0815 ***"give me an example"***: My **first** comment, second link, addresses this. ***"need to monitor the value of MLB.currentselection"***: You **allready** do this, read my last comment again. Setup a [GitHub Project](https://github.com/collections/learn-to-code), there I can go supporting you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Question**: `MultiListbox` custom event binding problem, click on any of the list elements, trigger the `print_stuff_x function`

Implement a custom event `'<<MultiListboxSelect>>'` which get fired on processed a `'<<ListboxSelect>>'` event and `.bind(...` at it.

---

**Reference**:

- [Tkinter.Widget.event_generate-method](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.event_generate-method)
- [event generate](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/event.htm#M7)

  > Generates a window event and arranges for it to be processed just as if it had come from the window system. If the `-when` option is specified then it determines when the event is processed.

---

**Crore Point**:

```
self.event_generate('<<MultiListboxSelect>>', when='tail')
```

---

```
class MultiListbox(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, lists):
        ...
        for l,w in lists:
            ...
            lb = tk.Listbox(frame, ...
            lb.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>', self._select)

    def _select(self, event):
        w = event.widget
        curselection = w.curselection()

        if curselection:
            self.event_generate('<<MultiListboxSelect>>', when='tail')
            ...

class ClassTwo:
    ...

    def create_elements(self):
        self.available_images_lb = MultiListbox(self.frame, ...
        ...
        self.available_images_lb.bind('<<MultiListboxSelect>>', self.print_stuff_two)
        ...

class ClassThree:
    ...

    def create_elements(self):  
        self.image_parts_info_lb = MultiListbox(self.frame, ...
        ...
        self.image_parts_info_lb.bind('<<MultiListboxSelect>>', self.print_stuff_three)
```

Comment: Again a huge thank you @stovfl ! In case someone is interested in a simple implementation, here is the link to a [Github repo](https://github.com/n00by0815/Image-Viewer) that implements his suggestion.